# Customize close icon in searchview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

How can I change the res of closeIcon of searchview. Using Holo.light as parent. I have tried lots of things! This name isn't on Holo!!

```
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_search_close</item>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using AppCompat v21 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` you can use this:

```
values/themes.xml:
<style name=”Theme.MyTheme” parent=”Theme.AppCompat”>
    <item name=”searchViewStyle”>@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name=”MySearchViewStyle” parent=”Widget.AppCompat.SearchView”>
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
    <item name="submitBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Close button icon -->
    <item name="closeIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
    <item name="goIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Voice search button icon -->
    <item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
    <item name="commitIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

Found here: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

If you want consistency I would advice to use this library.

If you really don't want to use this library you can use this to change the close icon:

```
int closeButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);  
ImageView closeButtonImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(closeButtonId);  
closeButtonImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
```

Got it from here: http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

Comment: I had problems Styling Appcompat theme so I'm using holo theme instead!

Comment: @IamaDeveloper Then look at the second part. You can use the second part to change the close button on a normal theme. But I'd still advice to try again and use `AppCompat`

Comment: thanks That worked. Why appcompat? I have to change all of my code. like  actionbar to supportactionbar ... and also I couldn't style appcompat

Comment: `AppCompat` is made for consistency across android versions. I think it is now the standard way to do things and Google made it highly customizable. You could also have a look at my link, there is more information on how to style with `AppCompat`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`, you can also customize it in the layout XML:

```
app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_search_close"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void changeCloseIcon(SearchView searchView) {    
    ImageView closeButtonImage = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    closeButtonImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_toolbar_close);
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    changeCloseIcon(searchView);      
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin use as below. It is important to handle it in onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
   import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView: SearchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    val closeIcon = searchView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn)
    closeIcon.setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            requireContext(),
            R.color.radio_tab_text_color
        )
    )
}
```

For implementing drawable file;

```
closeIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_close)
```

Note: Check if you have imported androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView